# Convert timestamp to america/newyork timezone in angular 2

Tags: angular

how can i convert "startTime":1498861504, to specific america /newyork time zone in angular 2

do i need to create pipe for the i would be helpful if a snippet of code could be provided

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display results on view you can do this

```
{{ date_expression | date : format : timezone}}
```

For further details https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date